# Do I need to restart WebSphere server after MQ server restarted

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq

I am implementing JMS and MDB on WAS server and Configured IBM MQ as MOM. My MQ server goes down for maintenance on every weekend. I wanted to know if I need to restart Was server as well after MQ server comes up.

I can't test it in lower environment as they dont restart server in these region.

Comment: Suggest you to refer to this link: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/202765/after-restarting-the-websphere-mq-qmgr-the-websphe.html

Comment: Thanks this helped